# Why is this code never jumping to the label named true?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, dos

I been trying to figure out why my code is not working.

I need to implement this cmp in a bigger version of this code as a main menu asking for options to proceed with certain actions however when comparing `al, '1'` is not recognizing `je` and it jumps directly to `jne`.

I know that probably that's the error when comparing but what is the correct way to do it?

```
.model small

.stack 100h

.data

wm db 0ah, 0dh, "Welcome! please select one of the following options: $"

op1 db 0ah, 0dh, "Please submit 1 to true and 2 to false: $"

op1_1 db 0ah, 0dh, "its true!!! $"

op1_2 db 0ah, 0dh, "its false!!!! $"


.code

main PROC

    mov ax,@data

    mov ds, ax  
    mov dx, offset wm
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h  

    mov dx, offset op1
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    mov ah, 0ah
    int 21h

    cmp al, '1'
    je true
    jne false


success:

    mov ah,4ch                   ; function: DOS Exit Program
    mov al, 0                    ; specify return code 0
    int 21h                    ; adios amigo!

true:

    mov dx, offset op1_1
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    jmp success

false:

    mov dx, offset op1_2
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    jmp success

main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: Please prefer to make your questions stand out by making them good questions, rather than marking them up with symbols.

Comment: Added bold to the question so you can be able to separate the question from the code. I put the code as reference of what I'm doing however I specified at first what I was trying to accomplish

Comment: You should put all your code inside a code block. I don't know asm so can't be sure I'm doing it correctly.

Comment: Use a debugger to single-step your code.  I guess you already are?  Presumably `al` isn't `'1'`, otherwise it would jump to `true`, assuming your assembler handles ASCII character constants the expected way.  (Check with a disassembler if you're not sure.)  Anyway, use your debugger to look at `al`.

Comment: 'mov ah, 0ah' you call the wrong function. you proably want int 21h/8 which returns the pressed char in AL

Answer (score 5):

You are not passing enough information to function `0ah` with

```
mov ah, 0ah
int 21h
```

which requires buffer information and inputs a sequence of characters into a user-supplied buffer. I suggest you use

```
mov ah, 08h
int 21h
```

which returns a single character in `al` as you are expecting. It does not echo the character, but function `01h` does.